# Elasticsearch works for one term in must, but not two

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to query with Elasticsearch to find documents with 2 matching conditions:

Here's the mapping in use:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "stores": {
            "properties": {
                "locality": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "city": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "type": {
                    "type": "integer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's my filter:

```
{
  "query": {
      "constant_score": {
            "filter": {
                "bool" : {
                    "must" : [
                        {
                            "term" : { "locality": "Shivajinagar" }
                        }, {
                            "term" : { "city": "Bangalore" }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

No matter what values I try I always get:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

Even though Data exists(all documents search):

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 10742,
    "max_score": 1.0,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test_es",
        "_type": "stores",
        "_id": "942",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "type": 2,
          "locality": "Palam Vihar",
          "city": "Gurgaon"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test_es",
        "_type": "stores",
        "_id": "944",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "type": 2,
          "locality": "Chirag Dilli",
          "city": "Delhi"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test_es",
        "_type": "stores",
        "_id": "948",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "type": 1,
          "locality": "Vashi",
          "city": "Navi Mumbai"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test_es",
        "_type": "stores",
        "_id": "980",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "type": 3,
          "locality": "Sector 48",
          "city": "Faridabad"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test_es",
        "_type": "stores",
        "_id": "982",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "type": 2,
          "locality": "Kammanahalli",
          "city": "Bangalore"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test_es",
        "_type": "stores",
        "_id": "984",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "type": 3,
          "locality": "Tilak Nagar",
          "city": "Delhi"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test_es",
        "_type": "stores",
        "_id": "742",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "type": 3,
          "locality": "Shivajinagar",
          "city": "Bangalore"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test_es",
        "_type": "stores",
        "_id": "752",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "type": 1,
          "locality": "DLF Phase 3",
          "city": "Gurgaon"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test_es",
        "_type": "stores",
        "_id": "754",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "type": 3,
          "locality": "Electronic City",
          "city": "Bangalore"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test_es",
        "_type": "stores",
        "_id": "778",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "type": 2,
          "locality": "Bandra East",
          "city": "Mumbai"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried using query instead of filter, even though I don't really care about scores, but nada!

Where might I be going wrong?!

Comment: Use match instead of term :)

Comment: @ArchitSaxena Wow! That worked! Thanks!

Comment: you know why? Read this:https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html
particularly the `analyzer` section.

Comment: your text field is analyzed by the standard analyzer by default. read: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html
This means that your fields are being stored lowercased and tokenized by spaces etc. When you use `term` filter, it does not pass the keywords through the same analysis phase, as it does in match query. So it tries to compare: `Bangalore` to `bangalore`. Therefore, no matches.

Comment: @ArchitSaxena you should post this as an answer.

Comment: Posting answer, for the sake of SO guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer:** Use `match` instead of `term`.

**Long Answer:**

The important thing to know here is that your search keywords, like: `{ "locality": "Shivajinagar" }` and `{ "city": "Bangalore" }` need to be compared in the same form as they were stored. 
In the question, the mapping specifies that "locality" and "city" fields are of `type: text`. According to the documentation, `type: text` fields are analyzed by standard analyzer by default.

> The default `standard analyzer` drops most punctuation, breaks up text
>   into individual words, and lower cases them. For instance, the
>   standard analyzer would turn the string “Quick Brown Fox!” into the
>   terms [quick, brown, fox]. This analysis process makes it possible to
>   search for individual words within a big block of full text.
>
> The `term` query looks for the exact term in the field’s inverted
>   index — it doesn’t know anything about the field’s analyzer. This
>   makes it useful for looking up values in keyword fields, or in numeric
>   or date fields. When querying full text fields, use the match query
>   instead, which understands how the field has been analyzed.

So, when you search for "Bangalore" in a term query it looks for "Bangalore" in the city field while the index mapping had ensured that it was stored as "bangalore". That's why you get no matches.

You can find the documentation regarding the exact question here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html

**Side Tip:** Use the _analyze endpoint to check exactly what a particular analyzer emits on passing the input text.
Documentation for _analyze endpoint: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html